# Root compilation in OSX with true GCC/G++

Tags: osx, c++, cern-root

I need to compile ROOT with gcc/g++.  I am having difficulty with the objective C libraries.

If I link a true g++ (installed with `brew`) to the command `gg++` and the same for `gcc` -> `ggcc` - I can start to compile with

```
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=gg++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=ggcc <the rest of my options>
```

The compilation gets about 70% done before it gives me an error that "Option '-O' takes an integer argument".  I tracked this down.  In 'root/core/macosx/CMakeLists.txt', there is a line

```
set_source_files_properties(${sources} COMPILE_FLAGS "-ObjC++ -std=c++11")
```

So `g++` is not recognizing the Objective C flag.  I've changed this line to

```
set_source_files_properties(${sources} COMPILE_FLAGS "-x objective-c++-header -lobjc -std=c++11")
```

Which is the `g++` equivalent.  I've also tried `-x objective-c++`.  This attempt fails at around 70% with hundreds of errors.  It basically looks like the compiler does not understand the Objective C++.

Has anyone had success in compiling ROOT from source with `g++` on OSX (not `clang`)?

PS - As a side note, I believe `g++` in `/usr/bin` on OSX is actually a link to `clang` - verified on my machine by typing `g++ --version`. This is why I installed `g++` from `brew` and linked it to `gg++`.

---

- *ROOT Version:* Github Master branch, commit # 2762a32
- *Platform:* OSX
- *Compiler:* GCC 8.1.0

  ---

Comment: why not install it with brew, assuming this root is your root: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/root

Comment: Long story short - I'd like to use GEANT4 compiled with gcc because GEANT4 compiled with clang can't use a radioactive decay library I need.  I have to install all the libraries that GEANT4 needs, compiled with gcc in that case.  HepMC is one of those libraries, which uses ROOT.  I get errors when I link ROOT (from brew/compiled with clang) to HepMC while compiling HepMC with gcc.  That root, from brew, does work by itself though.  Thanks!